# Make Auto-Generated Comment when flagging as duplicate by community user, not by comment owner

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

When flagging a question as a duplicate, a comment is posted automatically.

Can you make the owner of that comment as [community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

I asked this request is, most duplicated questions are generated by new users and some may try to take revenge down voting and many believes that at flagging is a private channel between the flagger and the site's moderators.

Comment: New users cannot vote.

Comment: @SFTP As I know it needed only 125 rep to down vote...I believe still he/her is a new user... I believe me also new user since I also don't know many thing about SEO even I use a few months SO

Comment: If you're that concerned about revenge voting (I don't recall I was ever revenge down voted for offering a duplicate but YMMV) delete the comment immediately after you've flagged.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson What does SEO have to do with being a new user?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*"flagging is a private channel between the flagger and the site's moderators."*

Sure, but close-votes aren't private.
There's no privacy issue with these automated comments.

On the other hand, it allows the OP to @mention the (first) dupe close-voter, if necessary.